# python, xml: how to access the 3rd child by element' name

Tags: python, python-3.x, xml, xml-parsing, xquery

Would you help me, pleace, to get an access to elemnt with name 'id' by the following construction in Python (i have lxml and xml.etree.ElementTree libraries).

Desirable result: '0000000'
Desirable method:

1. Search in xml-document a child, where it's name is fcsProtocolEF3.
2. Search in fcsProtocolEF3 an element with name 'id'.

It is crucial to search by element name. Not by ordinal position.

I tried to use something like this: `tree.findall('{http://zakupki.gov.ru/oos/export/1}fcsProtocolEF3')[0].findall('{http://zakupki.gov.ru/oos/types/1}id')[0].text`

it works, but it requires to input namespaces. XML-document have different namespaces and I don't know how to define them beforehand.

Thank you.

That would be great to use something like XQuery in SQL:

```
value('(/*:export/*:fcsProtocolEF3/*:id)[1]', 'nvarchar(21)')) AS [id],
```

XML-document:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="true"?>
 <ns2:export xmlns:ns3="http://zakupki.gov.ru/oos/common/1" xmlns:ns4="http://zakupki.gov.ru/oos/base/1" xmlns:ns2="http://zakupki.gov.ru/oos/export/1" xmlns:ns10="http://zakupki.gov.ru/oos/printform/1" xmlns:ns11="http://zakupki.gov.ru/oos/control99/1" xmlns:ns9="http://zakupki.gov.ru/oos/SMTypes/1" xmlns:ns7="http://zakupki.gov.ru/oos/pprf615types/1" xmlns:ns8="http://zakupki.gov.ru/oos/EPtypes/1" xmlns:ns5="http://zakupki.gov.ru/oos/TPtypes/1" xmlns:ns6="http://zakupki.gov.ru/oos/CPtypes/1" xmlns="http://zakupki.gov.ru/oos/types/1">
   <ns2:fcsProtocolEF3 schemeVersion="10.2">
     <id>0000000</id>
     <purchaseNumber>0000000000000000</purchaseNumber>
   </ns2:fcsProtocolEF3>
 </ns2:export>
```

Comment: Please upload a VALID xml. The current one is not valid

Comment: balderman, thank you for responce. I've added the end in the document.

Comment: What is wrong with your current solution? Since the XML doc is based on NS - you must use them. Dont you? What do you expect to have?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

lxml solution:

```
xml = '''<?xml version="1.0"?>
 <ns2:export xmlns:ns3="http://zakupki.gov.ru/oos/common/1" xmlns:ns4="http://zakupki.gov.ru/oos/base/1" xmlns:ns2="http://zakupki.gov.ru/oos/export/1" xmlns:ns10="http://zakupki.gov.ru/oos/printform/1" xmlns:ns11="http://zakupki.gov.ru/oos/control99/1" xmlns:ns9="http://zakupki.gov.ru/oos/SMTypes/1" xmlns:ns7="http://zakupki.gov.ru/oos/pprf615types/1" xmlns:ns8="http://zakupki.gov.ru/oos/EPtypes/1" xmlns:ns5="http://zakupki.gov.ru/oos/TPtypes/1" xmlns:ns6="http://zakupki.gov.ru/oos/CPtypes/1" xmlns="http://zakupki.gov.ru/oos/types/1">
   <ns2:fcsProtocolEF3 schemeVersion="10.2">
     <id>0000000</id>
     <purchaseNumber>0000000000000000</purchaseNumber>
   </ns2:fcsProtocolEF3>
 </ns2:export>'''
 
from lxml import etree as et

root = et.fromstring(xml)
text = root.xpath('//*[local-name()="export"]/*[local-name()="fcsProtocolEF3"]/*[local-name()="id"]/text()')[0]
print(text)
```

Comment: Alexandra, thank you very much. This is exactly what I need. NS in the files may differ from file to file. The only thing is constant - the path: extport/fcsProtocolEF3/id. Therefore I needed a solution which doesn't use NS explicitly.

Answer (score 2):

Below is ET based solution. NS are in use.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

xml = '''<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
 <ns2:export xmlns:ns3="http://zakupki.gov.ru/oos/common/1" xmlns:ns4="http://zakupki.gov.ru/oos/base/1" xmlns:ns2="http://zakupki.gov.ru/oos/export/1" xmlns:ns10="http://zakupki.gov.ru/oos/printform/1" xmlns:ns11="http://zakupki.gov.ru/oos/control99/1" xmlns:ns9="http://zakupki.gov.ru/oos/SMTypes/1" xmlns:ns7="http://zakupki.gov.ru/oos/pprf615types/1" xmlns:ns8="http://zakupki.gov.ru/oos/EPtypes/1" xmlns:ns5="http://zakupki.gov.ru/oos/TPtypes/1" xmlns:ns6="http://zakupki.gov.ru/oos/CPtypes/1" xmlns="http://zakupki.gov.ru/oos/types/1">
   <ns2:fcsProtocolEF3 schemeVersion="10.2">
     <id>0000000</id>
     <purchaseNumber>0000000000000000</purchaseNumber>
   </ns2:fcsProtocolEF3>
 </ns2:export>

'''

def get_id_text():
  root = ET.fromstring(xml)
  fcs = root.find('{http://zakupki.gov.ru/oos/export/1}fcsProtocolEF3')
  # assuming there is one fcs element and one id under fcs
  return fcs.find('{http://zakupki.gov.ru/oos/types/1}id').text
print(get_id_text())
```

output

```
0000000
```